# What are the sysadmin-related conferences and events worth attending?

Tags: discussion, linux, windows, conferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conferences to go to 2011 Edition](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1089/conferences-to-go-to-2011-edition)

I would like to know your opinion on this subject and build a list of sysadmin-related conferences and events worth attending world wide.

Which ones have you attended? Do you recommend them? Which ones would you like to attend? Why?

Help building this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of sysadmin/scaling/infrastructure specific conferences](https://serverfault.com/questions/21139/list-of-sysadmin-scaling-infrastructure-specific-conferences) seems like a pretty thorough listing (albeit with old links).  I'd add [Velocity](http://a) to that list, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage  Windows environment, TechEd is always an informative conference.

\\Greg

Answer (score 1):

I also point out an earlier thread on this topic:

[Conferences to go to 2011 Edition](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1089/conferences-to-go-to-2011-edition)